# Filtering by current attribute value with xsl:if in a for-each

Tags: xslt

## Input

```
<topics>
  <topic author="john">
    <title>How to use a terminal</title>
  </topic>
  <topic author="john">
    <title>How to connect to the server</title>
  </topic>
  <topic author="mark">
    <title>How to query the DB</title>
  </topic>
</topics>
```

## What I am trying to do

I want to generate a file for each author, that lists only the titles of the topics that this author has written. So there would be a file for John, with 2 topic titles in it, and one for Mark, with one topic title in it.

File for John:

```
 - How to use a terminal
 - How to connect to the server
```

File for Mark:

```
 - How to query the DB
```

## What I've done

The part that generates a file for each person works fine. The part that generates the list is wrong, though. Here is my (wrong) xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="topics">    
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/topics/topic" group-by="@author">
        <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key( )}.html">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head/>
                <body>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/topics/topic">
                            <xsl:if test="@author='current()/@author'">
                                <li><xsl:value-of select="title"/></li>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>  
                    </ul>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `current-group()` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-group) so simply replace

```
               <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/topics/topic">
                        <xsl:if test="@author='current()/@author'">
                            <li><xsl:value-of select="title"/></li>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
```

with

```
               <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">

                            <li><xsl:value-of select="title"/></li>

                    </xsl:for-each>
```